# Weight of each criteria on final outcome

Tags: logic

I have a model that prioritizes sites based on chemical concentration (of 3 chemicals), movement (high, medium, or low) and impact (high, medium, or low). The figure below illustrates the model.

[image]

My question is what is the percent influence of each of the three categories (Chemical Concentration, Movement, and Impact) on the final outcome? Does each have a 33.3 percent influence on the outcome because each is considered equally? Or does the Chemical Concentration Category alter this because it contains its own categorization?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure which, but more tags should be included.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you mean by weight(if you have a more "formal" definition for it, it could help) but, I think that the Chemical Concentration category has more influence on the outcome than the other two, because of two reasons.

Firstly, knowledge of the Chemical Concentration always excludes a certain outcome. If $CR$ is high($H$), the outcome can't be low($L$). If $CR$ is medium($M$), the outcome can't be $H$. And if it is $L$, the outcome can't be high. The same can't be said for knowledge of any of the other two categories.

Secondly, if $CC$ (chemical concentration) takes the values $L,M,H$ each with probability $1/3$, and $impact$ also takes the values $L,M,H$ each with probability $1/3$, and $movement$ also takes the values $L,M,H$ each with probability $1/3$, then by knowing only the:

$-$ value of $CC$ and playing smartly, you can guess the outcome correctly with probability: $\frac{1}{3}*\frac{5}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{5}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{8}{9}=\frac{2}{3}$

$-$ value of $impact$ and playing smartly, you can guess the outcome correctly with probability: $\frac{1}{3}*\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{6}{9}=\frac{14}{27}<\frac{2}{3}$

$-$ value of $movement$ and playing smartly, you can guess the outcome correctly with probability: $\frac{1}{3}*\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{6}{9}=\frac{14}{27}<\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: I do not agree with your 2nd reason. All three categories are required to get the final result.

Comment: @reevesi You are right. I editted my answer